# How is a null value/array handled in postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-null

Let's say I have the following field and values:

```
ArrayField
[1,2,3]
[3,4,5]
[null,2,3,4]
null
[]
[null]
```

Would postgres save all these values as-is. Or would any of these values be invalid or converted to something else -- for example having `null` as a field value (is that converted to `[]`)?

Comment: `jsonb` or `integer[]`?

Comment: `[]`...........

Comment: `null` and an empty array `[]` are two different things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, all of your expressions are valid excepted for the last one: `'{null,}'`, which would raise error:

> malformed array literal: "{null,}"

It is also worth noting that there is a difference between `null` (and undefined value) and `{}` (an empty array). Say you want to write to a column has a `not null` constraint, `null` would fail while `{}` would be allowed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c0fc570ad0019c4e51058daa349e907)**:

```
-- create the table
create table t (array_field int[])

-- insert values
insert into t values
    ('{1,2,3}'),
    ('{3,4,5}'),
    ('{null,2,3,4}'),
    (null),
    ('{}')
;
-- 5 rows affected

-- won't work
insert into t values ('{null,}');
-- ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{null,}"
-- LINE 1: insert into t values ('{null,}')
--                               ^
-- DETAIL:  Unexpected "}" character.
```

```
-- check the results
select array_field, array_length(array_field, 1) from t
```

```
array_field  | array_length
:----------- | -----------:
{1,2,3}      |            3
{3,4,5}      |            3
{NULL,2,3,4} |            4
null         |         null
{}           |         null
```

Comment: thanks for this, I updated the syntax for this. One question -- what would be an example where `[]` would be different than `null` in a practical usage (not just in terms of storage value)?

Comment: @David542: welcome. Well, you can see in my answer the example of an insert query against a non-nullable column.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL will not silently modify your arrays. If you stored `[NULL]`, it won't become `[]`. Your last example (`[NULL,]`) is syntactically incorrect.